# CollectionView Header ReusableView

Tags: swift, collectionview

I have enabled the header in the collectionView through storyboard, then I coded as follows, but Header does not show up. I wonder anyone see any issues?

**AskViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    askCollectionView.register(AskCollectionViewHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "askCollectionViewHeader")
    askCollectionView.delegate = self
    askCollectionView.dataSource = self
}


extension AskViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
     let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "askCollectionViewHeader", for: indexPath) as! AskCollectionViewHeader
     header.askHeaderTitle.text = "Hi"
     return header
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                      referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize{
    
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 200)
    }
}
```

**AskCollectionViewHeader.swift**

```
import UIKit

class AskCollectionViewHeader : UICollectionReusableView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var askHeaderTitle: UILabel!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering a class, but don't have anything that instantiates this view’s `askHeaderTitle`.

With collection view headers, you have three options:

1. Define the reusable view in your storyboard scene (by dragging a “Collection Reusable View” on to your collection view you set up in Interface Builder). In that case, you'd specify the class and the reuse identifier in IB, and you wouldn't call `register` in `viewDidLoad` at all, but rather let the storyboard take care of that.
2. Define the reusable view in a NIB. In that case, you'd register the NIB in IB, not the class.
3. Define the reusable view programmatically. Only in that case would you use `register` with the class. But then again, that subclass wouldn't use `@IBOutlet` (because you aren't defining it in IB), and you'd be creating the subviews programmatically.

I think option 1 is easiest, but obviously is only applicable if you are using storyboards and cell prototypes. Option 2 is useful if you have some reusable view that you plan on using from multiple view controllers. Option 3 is a technique one might employ if you want to do everything manually.

Comment: I have enabled the `CollectionView Header` in IB, and then added a `Label` inside the header and then create `ReusableViewClass` and add the label outlet. I registered it in the viewdidload as I described in my question, it does not work. Then I deleted register in the viewdidload, it did not work also.

Comment: @casillas - I don't know what to tell you, because when you do this in IB, you don't have to `register` anything. The IB does that for you. See https://github.com/robertmryan/CollectionViewDemo2. If you're still having troubles, create a [new, blank project with the bare essentials to manifest the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and upload it somewhere where we can take a look at it.